# iOS: How I can support firebase crashlytics in my development pod?

Tags: swift, firebase, cocoapods, crashlytics

I am making a development pod and integrating it into my current project. I want to get the logs in Firebase whenever any crash happens in my SDK, how can I proceed ahead?

I have already added the Firebase pod into my main project, and I do not want to add it again in the development pod. I am getting the crash logs but those are not pointing to the development pod and not currently in readable state, have some symbols in b/w. I have used DWARF with dSYM file option also.

Comment: I have already added the Firebase pod into my main project, and I do not want to add it again in the development pod. I am getting the crash logs but those are not pointing to the development pod and not currently in readable state, have some symbols in b/w. I have used DWARF with dSYM file option also.

Comment: Adding Crashlytics pod to the main app is the recommended way. Typically, the dSYMs of the .frameworks installed in the app (in this case your dev pod) should be available so when the upload-symbols script gets executed, all those symbols get uploaded. Another option could be manually uploading the dSYMs of the dev pod. Could you add a screenshot? It would be interesting to see what you are seeing in those crash reports.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the directions given [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/setup). Should be pretty straight forward. Don't forget to look at pricing since not all features of Firebase are free to use.

Comment: I have already added the Firebase pod into my main project, and I do not want to add it again in the development pod. I am getting the crash logs but those are not pointing to the development pod and not currently not in readable state, have some symbols in b/w. I have used DWARF with dSYM file option also.